# Webpack bundled library does not compile in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I'm trying to bundle a standalone library with Webpack (v5) and use it in my React application.

The `webpack.config.js` file is pretty straightforward:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './TestWebpack.js',
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
  output: {
    filename: 'widgets.bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'ClientApp', 'src', 'dynamicBundles'),
    library: {
      name: 'widgets',
      type: 'umd',
      umdNamedDefine: true,
    }
  },
  externals: {
    'react': {
        'commonjs': 'react', 
        'commonjs2': 'react', 
        'amd': 'react',
        'umd': 'react'
      },
    'react-dom': {
        'commonjs': 'react-dom',
        'commonjs2': 'react-dom',
        'amd': 'react-dom',
        'umd': 'react-dom'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-react'
            ],
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  },
};
```

The `TestWebpack.js` file is also very simple:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function TestWebpack(){
    return (
        <div>Test</div>
    )
}
```

But when I compile it with Webpack and use it in my React application like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import * as Widgets from '../dynamicBundles/widgets.bundle'

export default function TestUsingWebpack(){
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Object.keys(Widgets) - ', Object.keys(Widgets));
    }, []);

    return <div>Test</div>
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
  Line 12:  'define' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 13:   'define' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 18:   Unexpected use of 'self'  no-restricted-globals
```

I can't figure out how to solve this. I see in the bundled file that in these lines an undefined variable 'define' is used. I saw in other answers that people put lines at the start to define it properly, but this bundle may change frequently so it's not an answer.

Maybe there's something wrong with my Webpack config file? I'm new to this and tried following the newest articles and Webpack documentation about standalone library but it's still not working.

Comment: Those errors are from ESLint, not Webpack. Are you linting your build output, rather than just your source code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not linting, there is no ESLint configuration, at least in the bundles project. Should I add it?

Comment: `no-undef`, `no-restricted-globals` are ESLint rules: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef, https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals. It's not at all clear from what you've posted how and why they're coming into this.

Comment: It's not at all clear for me also why they're coming to this. I can provide you any additional info you need